# Using R, How can i get a 'cell' in 'column1' to update when Column2 on the same row contains a word?

Tags: r

Using R, is there a regex way that I get a 'cell' in 'Column1' to update when 'Column2' on the same row contains a word within its contents?

For example# If I wanted cells that contain 'time' anywhere in them to then update the matrix' Column1 to '10' as below

```
Column1        Column2 
 10            that is the time 
 10            what time is the match
 0                 where is the car?
```

Currently I can get it to work for non regex (only if the exact cell contents is 'time' using the below;

```
ds1$test[ds1$Column2 %in% "time"] <- 10
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
df1$Column1[grep("time", df1$Column2)] <- 10
```

Comment: A quick follow up question if I may. pretend that I wanted to target multiple keywords and their regex versions, would it be as the below;            <br/> df1$Column1[grep("time", "clocks", df1$Column2)] <- 10

Comment: @IanMcTavish  In that case, it would be `v1 <- c("time", "clocks"); pat <- paste0("\\b(", paste(v1, collapse="|"), ")\\b"); grep(pat, df1$Column2)`

Comment: Thanks! Would this version also assign the numerical value to Column1 if the text was detected in the corolated Column2 cell?

Comment: @IanMcTavish  You have to do similar to the previous step i.e. `df1$Column1[grep(pat, df1$Column2)] <- 10`  The assignment operator is `<-`